# Displaying count in SQL as alphabets instead of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am trying to work on a trigger which has a query as

```
Select Count(*) 
from table name
```

For example, it's displaying count as 2. Is it possible to get count as two in English?

Once this trigger runs on a table, I would get email Notifications (database Email). There are .... records being inserted.

To be honest I was not sure if it's possible to display Count total in Alphabets.

I was trying something with ASCII, but no idea How it will work?

Comment: Do <sql> and <server> combined mean <sql-server>?

Comment: SQL has no built-in number in digits to number in letters functionality. If you write your own routine, how big numbers do you want to handle?

Comment: This is a presentation issue, not a data issue. I'm pretty sure that there are libraries out there for the language you use in your application, what ever that application is.

Comment: FWIW, python has a library called [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) which seems to work quite well. C# has [humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer). I would google "{my language} number to words". If you're hellbent on doing it in SQL, you can probably adapt the implementations from those languages into SQL if you _really_ wanted to.

Comment: [use Oracle instead?](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-to-spell-a-number-or-convert-a-number-to-words-4794)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of a function that takes a number and type of words to generate and returns a word string:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_NUMBER_AS_STRING(@pNum VARCHAR(30), @pCulture INT = 1)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t TABLE (
        culture INT 
    ,   level int
    ,   frValue varchar(30) COLLATE database_default
    ,   toValue varchar(30) COLLATE database_default
    ,   name NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE database_default
    ,   accumulatable BIT
    )

    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,   @from VARCHAR(30)
    ,   @to VARCHAR(30)
    ,   @numLower VARCHAR(30)
    ,   @numHigher VARCHAR(30)
    ,   @acc BIT
    ,   @pNameHigher NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,   @pNameLower NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,   @level INT
    
    ;WITH lvl1 AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'five'), (6, 'six'), (7, 'seven'), (8, 'eight'), (9, 'nine')
        ,   (10, 'ten'), (11, 'eleven'), (12, 'twelve'), (13, 'thirteen'), (14, 'fourteen'), (15, 'fifteen'), (16, 'sixteen'), (17, 'seventeen'), (18, 'eighteen'), (19, 'nineteen')
        ) x (val, name)
    )
    , lvl_rest AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (20, 'twenty', 2), (30, 'thirty', 2), (40, 'fourty', 2), (50, 'fifty', 2), (60, 'sixty', 2), (70, 'seventy', 2), (80, 'eighty', 2), (90, 'ninety', 2)
        ,   (100., 'hundred', 3), (1000., 'thousand', 4), (1000000., 'million', 5), (1000000000., 'billion', 6), (1000000000000., 'trillion', 7)
        ) x(val, name, level)
    )
    INSERT INTO @t (culture, level, frValue, toValue, name, accumulatable)
    SELECT  1, LEN(t.val), CAST(t.val AS VARCHAR(30)), CAST(t.val AS VARCHAR(30)), t.name, 0
    FROM    lvl1 t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  1, 2, CAST(t.val AS VARCHAR(30)), lead(CAST(t.val - 1 AS VARCHAR(30)), 1, CONCAT(t.val-1, t.val- 1)) OVER(ORDER BY t.val), t.name, CASE WHEN LEN(val) < 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM    lvl_rest t;

    -- Fixed values
    INSERT INTO @t (culture, level, frValue, toValue, name, accumulatable)
    SELECT  2, -1, x.frValue, x.toValue, x.name, 0
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (N'Few', 1, 4),(N'Several', 5, 9),(N'Pack', 10, 19),(N'Lots', 20, 49),(N'Horde', 50, 99),(N'Throng', 100, 249),(N'Swarm', 250, 499),(N'Zounds', 500, 999),(N'Legion', 1000, 9999999999999999)
        ) x (name,frValue, toValue)

    -- figure out which level we're at
    SELECT  @level = CASE WHEN level < 0 OR @pNum = frValue THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
    ,   @name = t.name
    ,   @from = t.frValue
    ,   @to = t.toValue
    ,   @acc = t.accumulatable
    FROM    @t t
    WHERE   culture = @pCulture
    AND RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 30) + @pNum, 30) BETWEEN RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 30) + frValue, 30) AND RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 30) + toValue, 30)

    IF @level < 0
    BEGIN
        RETURN(@name)
    END
    -- Get the lower part and the higher part of the number
    SELECT  @numHigher = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@pNum AS NUMERIC(38, 0)) / CAST(@from AS NUMERIC(38, 0))) AS NUMERIC(38,0))
    ,   @numLower = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@pNum AS NUMERIC(38, 0)) % CAST(@from AS NUMERIC(38, 0))) AS NUMERIC(38,0))

    --select @name, @pNum, @numHigher, @numLower
    IF @acc = 1
        SELECT  @pNameHigher = dbo.FN_NUMBER_AS_STRING(@numHigher, @pCulture)

    IF @numLower > 0
        SELECT  @pNameLower = dbo.FN_NUMBER_AS_STRING(@numLower, @pCulture)
    RETURN(ISNULL(@pNameHigher+ ' ', '') + @name + ISNULL(' ' + @pNameLower, ''))
    
END
```

Testcode for english:

```sql
SELECT  num, dbo.FN_NUMBER_AS_STRING(num, 1)
from (
    values(1),(13), (29), (10000034)
) x (num)
```

Testcode for heroes:

```sql
SELECT  num, dbo.FN_NUMBER_AS_STRING(num, 2)
from (
    values(1),(13), (29), (203), (4333)
) x (num)
```

The function is pretty simple, it has a table of ranges and names for start of the range as well as some flags that controls how the range works.

A range is either accumulatable ie. one should take the lower parts separately (for example: 1234 consists of 1000 + 200 + 30 + 4, but 511 breaks down to 500 + 11; 11 is not accumulated by 10 + 1 since it has own name).

Finally, for every number, we find its range level and then recursively calculate the upper and lower parts.

For example:

```
123456 breaks down to following:
level= 1000, upper part= 123, lower part= 456.
123 breaks down to:
level= 100, upper part=1, lower part=23, generates 100
23 breaks down to:
level=20, upper part=1, lower part=3, generates 20
```

Both 1 and 3 are not breakable, so they are the end.

Finally one constructs the upper + level + lower part, which becomes: one hundred twenty three thousand.
Similarly, 456 is broken down the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The following code generates a set of Arabic/Roman values, thus providing "alphabets instead of numbers":

```
with
  ArabicRomanConversions as (
    select Arabic, Ones, Tens, Hundreds, Thousands
      from ( values
        ( 0, '', '', '', '' ), ( 1, 'I', 'X', 'C', 'M' ), ( 2, 'II', 'XX', 'CC', 'MM' ), ( 3, 'III', 'XXX', 'CCC', 'MMM' ), ( 4, 'IV', 'XL', 'CD', '?' ),
        ( 5, 'V', 'L', 'D', '?' ), ( 6, 'VI', 'LX', 'DC', '?' ), ( 7, 'VII', 'LXX', 'DCC', '?' ), ( 8, 'VIII', 'LXXX', 'DCCC', '?' ), ( 9, 'IX', 'XC', 'CM', '?' )
        ) as Placeholder ( Arabic, Ones, Tens, Hundreds, Thousands )
      ),
  Numbers as (
    select 1 as Number
    union all
    select Number + 1
      from Numbers
      where Number < 3999 )
  select Number as Arabic,
    ( select Thousands from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number / 1000 ) +
    ( select Hundreds from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number / 100 % 10 ) +
    ( select Tens from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number / 10 % 10 ) +
    ( select Ones from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number % 10 ) as Roman
    from Numbers option ( MaxRecursion 3998 );
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cIBaLOjr).

All you need to do is select the appropriate value.